# set image with canvas inside an embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The message is edited correctly if I add text, title... but don't add the image in .setImage(), it doesn't bring the image. Any idea?

```
      const img = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'img.png');
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setImage('attachment://img.png')

  client.channels.cache.get("channel id").messages.fetch("msg id")
  .then(msgg => msgg.edit({embeds: [embed]}))
```

*I have created the image with canvas previously, if I insert the image outside the embed, it works correctly*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit the message you need to pass along the file.

```js
msgg.edit({ embeds: [embed], files: [img]})
```